# Relation between subdifferential and functionals

Tags: convex-analysis, functional-equations

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space and let $x,y\in X$ be non-zero. Suppose that

$\|x+ty\|\geq \|x\|$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\phi(t) := \|x+ty\|$. It is easy to see that $\phi$ attains minimum $t=0$. Consequently, the subdifferenetial of $\phi$ at $0$ (written as $\partial \phi(0)$) contains $0$.

**From this can we conclude the following:**

$\exists$ $x^*\in X^*$ such that $\|x^*\|=1$ with $x^*(x)=\|x\|$ and $Re~x^*(y)=0$.

I am a beginner in functional analysis and a detailed answer will be of great help.

**Edit:** Actually, in real case, the result can be obtained by a straighforward application of Hahn-Banach Theorem, by defining a functional $f: span\{x,y\}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(\alpha x+\beta y)= \alpha\|x\|$. However, in case of complex Banach spaces, we cannot use $span \{x,y\}$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, definitely @Theobendit

Comment: Well, there goes my suggestion!

Comment: Are you saying about the current edit I made? @TheoBendit

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was just going to use Hahn-Banach to extend the functional over $\operatorname{span}\{y\}$. If you can prove the real case by similar means, and you know that this doesn't extend, then my ideas are of little value to you.

Comment: Actually, we need to modify $span\{x,y\}$ or think of any other ways! Thank you @TheoBendit for your kind reply and time.

Comment: I think you idea of work with $span\{y\}$ may be of help to me. Will you kindly elaborate @TheoBendit

Comment: Essentially, it's much the same. Define $\phi$ over the span of $y$; it has a minimum at $0$, so the $0$ functional on $\operatorname{span}\{y\}$ is a subgradient on this space. Define the sublinear function $f(h)$ by the directional derivative of the norm function at $x$ in direction $h$. Extend this sublinear function to all of $X$, and the properties should fall out.

Comment: @TheoBendit, I am not much familiar to the concept of subgradient, directional derivative in Banach spaces and subdifferential, if you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a proof in the real case, as requested in the comments.

Let $Y = \operatorname{span}\{y\}$ and define
$$\phi : Y \to \Bbb{R} : z \mapsto \|x + z\|.$$
Then $\phi$ is convex. Note that $\phi$ attains a minimum at $0$, hence the $\mathbf{0}$ functional in $Y^*$ minorises $\phi$. That is,
$$\mathbf{0}(z) = 0 \le \phi(z),$$
for all $z \in Y$. Let
$$f : X \to \Bbb{R} : h \mapsto \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\|x + th\| - \|x\|}{t}.$$
That is, $f(h)$ is the directional derivative of $\|\cdot\|$ at $x$, in direction $h$. In particular, this means that $f$ is sublinear. Further, clearly $f(h) \ge 0$ for $h \in \operatorname{span} Y$.

Using Hahn-Banach theorem, we can extend $\mathbf{0}$ to a linear functional $x^* \in X$ such that $x^*(h) \le f(h)$ for all $h \in X$. I claim that $x^*$ satisfies the conditions we want.

Note that $x^*(y) = 0$ for $z \in Y$, since $x^*(z) = \mathbf{0}(z) = z$ for all $z \in Y$. We also have,
$$x^*(x) \le f(x) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\|x + tx\| - \|x\|}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0 +}\frac{t\|x\|}{t} = \|x\|$$
and
$$x^*(-x) \le f(-x) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\|x - tx\| - \|x\|}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0 +}\frac{(1 - t - 1)\|x\|}{t} = -\|x\|,$$
where we restrict our attention to $t \in (0, 1]$. Together, we get
$$x^*(x) = \|x\|,$$
as required.

Note that this implies $\|x^*\| \ge 1$. We also have, for $z \in X$,
$$x^*(z) \le f(z) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\|x + tz\| - \|x\|}{t} \le \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\|x\| + t\|z\| - \|x\|}{t} = \|z\|,$$
thus $\|x^*\| = 1$ as required.

Comment: Thank you so much @Theobendit. I will let you know, once I verify it.

Comment: It might be useful to recall that one-sided derivatives of convex functions do exist (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816383/convexity-and-proof-of-one-sided-derivative), so $f$ is indeed well-defined.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks! We need even more though: that $f$ is sublinear, and I was sort of taking it for granted that the reader would know this. Alternatively, one could use the Hahn-Banach separation theorem to separate the line $Y \times \{0\}$ from the interior of the epigraph of $\|\, \cdot + x\|$.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. The positive homogenity is easy to show, but the subaddivitivity I cannot prove on the spot.

Comment: It follows from the convexity of the function (positive homogeneity holds for general functions). Note that$$f(h_1 + h_2)=2f\left(\frac{h_1+h_2}{2}\right)=2\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\phi\left(\tfrac{h_1+h_2}{2}\right)-\phi(0)}{t}\le2\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\frac{\phi(th_1)+\phi(th_2)}{2}-\phi(0)}{t}=f(h_1)\\+f(h_2).$$